# Accessing <iframe> for content on Etherpad using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, dom, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a typographical chrome plguin for EtherPad sites. Problem is I don't know how to remove inline css of `<body>` in `iframe` within an `iframe` on etherpad using jQuery

If you open an etherpad doc, let's say on http://typewith.me, there is html that goes like:

```
<body id="innerdocbody" class="syntax safari authorColors doesWrap" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px; ">
```

I just need to remove style attribute using jQuery.
(I am a CSS guy, new to jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body', $('iframe#yourIframeID').contentDocument).removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run a content script inside iframes you need to enable `all_frames` flag in the manifest. More about it [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just wrote a quick function that will do a getElementById in all the iframes in the document, recursively, and return the first one it finds.

```
function getElementByIdInFrames(id, base) {
  var el;
  if(el = base.document.getElementById(id)) {
    return el;
  }

  for(var i = 0, len = base.frames.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(el = getElementByIdInFrames(id, base.frames[i])) {
      return el;
    }
  }
}
```

With this, you can use the following code to remove the styleAttribute from #innerdocbody

```
getElementByIdInFrames("innerdocbody", window).removeAttribute('style');
```